# When does socket.recv(recv_size) return?

Tags: python, sockets

From test, I concluded that in following three cases the `socket.recv(recv_size)` will return.

1. After the connection was closed. For example, the client side
   called socket.close() or any socket error occurred, it would return
   empty string.
2. Some data come, the size of data is more than `recv_size`.
3. Some data come, the size of data is less than `recv_size` and no more data come after a short time (I found 0.1s would work).

More details about #3:

```
#server.py

while True:
    data = sock.recv(10)
    print data, 'EOF'

#client1.py

sock.sendall("12345")
sock.sendall("a" * 50)

#client2.py

sock.sendall("12345")
time.sleep(0.1)
sock.sendall("a" * 50)
```

When I run `client1.py`, the `server.py` echos:

```
12345aaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaa EOF
```

When I run `client2.py`, the `server.py` echos:

```
12345 EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
aaaaaaaaaa EOF
```

Are my conclusions correct? Where can I see the official description about #3?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv

Comment: Thanks, but the manual did not answer my question.

Comment: How about here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv

Comment: I don't think your #2 case should ever happen.  If recv() is returning more than the number of bytes your specified in the argument you passed in, that is a bug.   (Btw for #3: sleeping to wait for more data is a bad idea, it will make your I/O routines slower than they need to be.... you should use an event-driven approach instead, either something like select(), or blocking I/O calls)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, your conclusion is correct. `socket.recv` is a blocking call.

`socket.recv(1024)` will read at most 1024 bytes, blocking if no data is waiting to be read. If you don't read all data, an other call to `socket.recv` won't block.

`socket.recv` will also end with an empty string if the connection is closed or there is an error.

If you want a non-blocking socket, you can use the select module (a bit more complicated than just using sockets) or you can use `socket.setblocking`.

I had issues with `socket.setblocking` in the past, but feel free to try it if you want.

Comment: I didn't see any official description about my conclusion 3).

Comment: socket.recv will read what is ready to be read when the call to recv is made. It does not matter if the amount read is less than the max size, the socket will unblock as soon as it can read data.

Comment: You can also call recv() as nonblocking if you give the right flag for it:
`socket.recv(10240, 0x40) # 0x40 = MSG_DONTWAIT a.k.a. O_NONBLOCK`
Please note that you have to catch the
`[Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable`
exceptions when there is no input data.

Comment: when I am doing `msg = socket.recv(1024)`, then `len(msg)` is `1024`. However, when I do `msg = socket.recv(10485760)` (10 MB), then `len(msg)` is `8760`...why this can be? Is it like input socket buffer has max size of `8760` bytes, and hence, whenever we try to read more data than `8760` bytes, it still returns only `8760` bytes

Comment: the parameter to socket.recv is the *maximum length* of the message to read at once. It will try to read up to that number, but no more, then return the read value. If you expect to receive more data than that, you can try to recv later on, or wait for more data to be received before calling the recv method.

Comment: If there is an error an exception is thrown, not an empty string returned.

Comment: @Martin I think that it's not always true "If you don't read all data, an other call to `socket.recv` won't block.". If you have a `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` socket and you don't read all bytes of a datagram, bytes that are not read are discarded.

Comment: Where can I find the documentation about,
`socket.recv will also end with an empty string if the connection is closed or there is an error.`

Answer (score 4):

It'll have the same behavior as the underlying recv libc call see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) for an official description of behavior (or read a more [general description](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/sockets.html) of the sockets api).

Answer (score 2):

I think you conclusions are correct but not accurate.

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket) indicates,  `socket.recv`  is majorly  focused on the network buffers.

When socket is blocking, `socket.recv` will return as long as the network buffers have bytes. If bytes in the network buffers are more than `socket.recv` can handle, it will return the maximum number of bytes it can handle. If bytes in the network buffers are less than `socket.recv` can handle, it will return all the bytes in the network buffers.