# Strange behaviour with recv() method in Python

Tags: python, networking, recv

I'm working on a network program in Python. It works well but I don't understand why.
Here's a part of my main loop :

```
while self.continue :
        message = ""
        try :
            message = self.connexion.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        except :
            pass
```

What is troubling to me is that the `recv(1024)` instruction should return a limited number of characters (1024 at most I imagine).
But it always returns the entire message even if his length is higher than 1024.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Maybe that's because of that loop? It's just like foreach with data.pop (I'm really not sure about this, but sounds legit).

Comment: Some problems may prevent good answers to your question. The loop is confusing. We don't see how the `continue` variable is controlled. `try-pass` also hides any potential errors. You're overwriting the `message` variable in each loop iteration. `connexion`, we _assume_ it's a socket object. `Utf8` doesn't look valid, it probably should be `utf-8`. It's very difficult to find the problem with this piece of code, try to produce a smaller example with less factors. The documentation of `recv` contradicts what you say is happening, so all these other factors may be obscuring the problem

Comment: I think this post will be probably useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174927/when-does-socket-recvrecv-size-return

Comment: It's not actually possible to have a `self.continue` attribute, because `continue` is a keyword.