# I am having trouble understanding the recv command in python? for sockets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

If I do s.recv(6) does that receive the first 6 bytes of data? I am looking at the documentation, and getting confused.

Comment: Can you be any more explicit about what's confusing you?

Comment: I guess I just want to know if doing recv(6) receives the first 6 bytes of data or not lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174927/when-does-socket-recvrecv-size-return

Comment: @ItachiSan I guess I'm just having a hard time understanding why you couldn't tell that from the documentation, or what reason you have to think it might do anything other than receiving the first 6 bytes of data.

Answer (score 1):

`bufsize` value in `recv` sets *maximum* amount of data received. So - yes, you will receive first 6 bytes or less (it depends of actual  length of data).
Additional information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708835/python-socket-receive-incoming-packets-always-have-a-different-size)

Comment: Is there a way to increase the byte size of a string?

Comment: You can set a larger `bufsize`