# Shut down a socket server - Python

Tags: python, sockets

I have been trying for so long to create a chat between 2 clients.
I also need to check if 1 client is disconnecting so the server will be shut down.

I have no idea why it isn't working, can someone help me?

**This is my code:**

```
from threading import Thread
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 1234))
s.listen(5)
def handleclient(sender,reciever):
    while True:
        data = sender.recv(1024)
        if data == "":
             close()
        else:
            reciever.send(data)
def close():
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    s.close()
    print ("closed")
while True:
    (client_s, client_addr) = s.accept()
    (client_s1, client_addr1) = s.accept()
    t = Thread(target=handleclient, args=(client_s,client_s1))
    t1 = Thread(target=handleclient, args=(client_s1,client_s))
    t.start()
    t1.start()
```

Comment: Does [When does socket.recv(recv_size) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174927/when-does-socket-recvrecv-size-return) answer your question? you aren't sending anything to `sender` but it is the first statement in the while loop.

Comment: Did you read the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket) in the Python documentation?

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because you have written code before knowing what you wanted it to do... A bit nitpicking, but you really you first describe in english (or whatever your first language is) what is expected to happen.

Apart from that, there is a true mistake in `if data == "":` `recv` returns a **byte** string, so it should at least be `if data == b"":`.

Another problem lies at `s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)`. `s` is not in connected state (like `sender` or `reciever` are) but in *listening* state. It does not make sense to shutdown it and it should raise an error.

But cleanly closing the server is not that easy. The main thread is waiting on `accept` on `s`. If you close it from another thread you will get an exception, so you have to protect it in a try block.

And you should decide what should happen for the main thread when a conversation between 2 clients ends. Currently you are trying to stop the server, but then the `while True` loop around the `accept` calls does not really make sense. Without knowing that I cannot propose you a fixed code...

Comment: Doesn't `sender.recv(1024)` block if nothing is being sent? ... Stopping the while loop in its tracls?

Comment: @wwii: it does but in the child threads. It is indeed possible to implement a [graceful shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777498/3545273) in the child threads, but that does not say what to do in the main one with the listening socket.

Comment: I'll have to remember that phrase.