# Simple TCP socket server, browser stalls on GET

Tags: python, http, sockets, tcp, httprequest

I have the following code for a simple Server that handles GET requests from the browser over TCP.

```
    while True:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind(('127.0.0.1', int(args.port)))
            print(f'TCP Server listening on port {args.port}...')
            s.listen()
            connection, addr = s.accept()
            print(f'Connected by {addr}')
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(args.buf)
                if not data:
                    print('Connection closed')
                    break
                message = data.decode()
                response = handle_request(message)
                connection.sendall(response)
            connection.close()
```

This works somewhat, but not really. When the browser GETs a PNG or html file, that it has cached (if-modified-since), it works seamlessly. However, when it has to serve a new file, the browser (Safari) stalls until I shut down the server but then mysteriously shows the actual file the browser was trying to GET.

I wonder if this has something to do with my implementation of the connection, but I assume that it more likely has to do with my http headers.

This is what my simple headers and response to the browser look like:

```
    header = f"HTTP/1.1 {status}\r\n" \
             f"Host: {header_dict['host']}\r\n" \
             f"Date: {datetime.today().strftime(time_format)}\r\n" \
             f"Last-Modified: {mod_time}\r\n" \
             f"Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n" \
             f"\r\n".encode()

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        payload = f.read()

    response = header + payload
```

Is there anything important missing from the header for Safari (or any other browser) to work with it? Thanks!

Comment: How would the client/browser know how large the payload is? Either close the connection after the payload has been sent (probably not what you should do after specifying `Connection: Keep-Alive`), or specify `Content-Length` in your header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does socket.recv(recv\_size) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174927/when-does-socket-recvrecv-size-return)

Comment: You are telling the browser to keep the connection alive, while waiting for the browser to send another request (which it won't).

Comment: And if the request is bigger than `args.buf`, then you will get multiple partial requests.

Comment: Thanks, seems like it was just missing the content-length. May have some other issues, but seems to have fixed it.

Comment: `recv` is byte oriented. It may well return less than the size requested. You may have received a partial message. For instance, `data.decode()` may fail if the recv ends in the middle of a multi-byte character. As an aside, specify the encoding and include that in the header. Right now you assume the default encoding for this python instance is what the browser is using.

Answer (score 0):

As KompjoeFriek commented, the browser needs to know how much data it is getting from the server. So the content-length header is necessary when handling a get request to serve some data. Without it, it waits until the connection is closed to show the data it has received. Adding a content-length header solved the problem.